# Window Media player adding Grids on playing video using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have developed coding in vb.net to insert media player and also i am able to add all features to media player like time, seek bar but for my project, it is mandatory to show flexible grid over the playing video which requires advanced level of programming.I learned to add lines grids on a form but forming grids over playing video and transform it size graphically is difficult,i would be glad if you help me...thank you in advance

**the following code help in forming grids but it cannot be transformed and also it cannot be placed over media player**

```vb
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Sub DrawGrid(g As Graphics, origin As Point, rows As Integer, columns As Integer, cellSize As Size)
        Dim gridWidth As Integer = columns * cellSize.Width
        Dim gridHeight As Integer = rows * cellSize.Height
        Dim left As Integer = origin.X - (gridWidth \ 2)
        Dim right As Integer = origin.X + (gridWidth \ 2)
        Dim top As Integer = origin.Y - (gridHeight \ 2)
        Dim bottom As Integer = origin.Y + (gridHeight \ 2)

        For y As Integer = top To bottom + 1 Step cellSize.Height
            Dim pt1 As New Point(left, y)
            Dim pt2 As New Point(right, y)
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, pt1, pt2)
        Next
        For x As Integer = left To right + 1 Step cellSize.Width
            Dim pt1 As New Point(x, top)
            Dim pt2 As New Point(x, bottom)
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, pt1, pt2)
        Next
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, New Rectangle(origin.X - 5, origin.Y - 5, 10, 10))
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim origin As New Point(Me.ClientRectangle.Width \ 2, Me.ClientRectangle.Height \ 2)
        Dim cellSize As New Size(10, 10)
        Dim rowCount As Integer = 10
        Dim columnCount As Integer = 10
        DrawGrid(e.Graphics, origin, rowCount, columnCount, cellSize)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is it a winform or a wpf application? Is the grid size going to be same as the media player playing area?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing on Video within C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752016/drawing-on-video-within-c-sharp)

Comment: it is a windows form, the grid size is fixed but can be transformed to perspective grid based on the object or structure present in video

Comment: windows form application created using visual studio 2015